# Realtime SQL Results ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql, ajax, pagination

We are developing a web based application to run queries against our databases, so our ops team can execute queries through web based interfaces rather than loggin into the sql server.

Is there anyway i can show large results in realtime like its displayed in the query analyzer. i cannot use pagination here as the query will be written by the user every time.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is a little vague, with a simple ajax update, you can refresh a lot of things that would be consider 'realtime'

Comment: No I mean even in the Ajax.. if your query is returning 100000 results, page has to wait or show progress. what i mean is show the results which are fetched so far, like in query analyzer

Comment: ASP.NET is a stateless, disconnected system, as such it is not subject to the kind of delegate (or push) patterns that are required to meet the most strict definitions of "realtime". The browser must poll the web server to get updates, changes may not be "pushed", so the question is, How "neartime" is close enough to "realtime" for your needs?

Comment: I don't understand why you cant use paging?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you could use [infinite scroll](http://blog.devlpr.net/2011/04/12/jquery-infinite-scroll-with-mvc-2/)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could - I guess it would probably go a little bit like this:

1. User submits the query
2. Server executes the query and starts processing the results
3. When the server has read N rows (e.g. N = 100,000) the server sends back those N rows to the client, with a flag indicating that there are more results to come
4. The client displays those results and also submits another query "Give me some more results please"
5. The server continues to read rows from the results
6. Repeat from 3. until all rows have been read.

The key is choosing a good value for N - the smaller it is the more responsive the UI, however the larger it is the faster the overall transfer of results will be.

Comment: hi i could figure out this was what i have to do? but need some technical information? like any classes, methods to use?